# android HttpURLConnection wont desconnect?

Tags: android, connection

aim using `HttpURLConnection` inside `AsyncTask` when i cancel `AsyncTask` and request abort or cancel the connection the `AsyncTask` stoped ok but `HttpURLConnection` still sending request and return with the values from the server

how i can make `HttpURLConnection` full stop cancel all requests or abort the request ?

this is the code i use

```
public static String post_string(String url, String urlParameters) throws IOException
    {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

         try {
              conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
             } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             Log.e(Logger, "MalformedURLException While Creating URL Connection - " + e.getMessage());
             throw e;
             } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Creating URL Connection - " + e.getMessage());
             throw e;
             }

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //if has Post inputs
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.length()));    

        OutputStream os = null; 
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

        try {
          os = conn.getOutputStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Creating URL OutputStream - " + e.getMessage());
         throw e;
      }
      try { 
           os.write(urlParameters.toString().getBytes());

        } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(Logger, "IOException While writting URL OutputStream - " + e.getMessage());
      throw e;
       }
      InputStream in = null;
       try {
          in = conn.getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Creating URL InputStream - " + e.getMessage());
         throw e;
       }
        String output = null;
        try {
            output = slurp(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Reading URL OutputStream - " + e.getMessage());
          throw e;
        } finally {
         try {
          os.close();
          in.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e(Logger, "IOException While Closing URL Output and Input Stream - " + e.getMessage());
        }
      }
      conn.disconnect();

      Log.i("Server output " , output);
      return output;
     }
     private static String slurp(InputStream in) throws IOException 
      {
            StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();

             byte[] b = new byte[4096];

              for (int n; (n = in.read(b)) != -1;) {

              out.append(new String(b, 0, n));

             }

           return out.toString();
     }
```

and this is what i use to abort connection

```
conn.disconnect();
```

any advice how to abort ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stop your `AsyncTask` like  `mTask.cancel(true);` just call `conn.disconnect();`

Comment: i did but the conn still working ! its returned with the values from server also its post the information to the server , that is truly weird

Comment: did you debug it? after disconnect no socket is opened and sure no data returns from server, post all your relevant code

Comment: yes i did debug it and LogCat print server return information after i disconnect the conn ! dose this happen because aim using `slurp(InputStream in)` ?

Comment: you have `finally { os.close();  in.close(); }`,  close it before conn.disconnect()

Comment: Still Same Problem when i cancel `AsyncTask` and close `os.close(); in.close();` LogCat still printing Server Response !

Comment: Sounds like your task still runs, please add logs to AsyncTask for each row where you get data from server, and where you close stream

Comment: i found the problem :D the conn return with responded String before i close the connection